# RNFIREBASE MESSENGER push notification not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, objective-c, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I m working on push notification RN firebase, I have followed the rnfirebase documentation, I get the remote message in console.log but not displaying the notifcation on the xcode simulator.

Below are the relevant files screenshots and code

**filename : notificationservices**
where i have added the respective react-native-firebase code snippets

```
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import {PushNotificationIOS} from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";
import {Platform} from "react-native";

const getFcmToken = async () => {
    const fcmToken = await messaging()
        .registerDeviceForRemoteMessages()
        .then(() => messaging().getToken());
    console.log("fcmToken ==>", fcmToken);

    if (fcmToken) {
        console.log("Your Firebase Token is:", fcmToken);
    } else {
        console.log("Failed", "No token received");
    }
};

export const requestUserPermission = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
        getFcmToken();
        console.log("Authorization status:", authStatus);
    }
};

export const notficationListener = async () => {
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
        console.log(
            "Notification caused app to open from background state:",
            remoteMessage.notification,
        );
    });
    messaging()
        .getInitialNotification()
        .then(remoteMessage => {
            if (remoteMessage) {
                console.log(
                    "Notification caused app to open from quit state:",
                    remoteMessage.notification,
                );
            }
        });
    messaging().onMessage(async remotemessage => {
        console.log("remote message11", JSON.stringify(remotemessage));
    });
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remotemessage => {
        console.log("remote message11", JSON.stringify(remotemessage));
        PushNotificationIOS.addNotificationRequest({
            id: remotemessage.messageId,
            title: remotemessage.notification.title,
            body: remotemessage.notification.body,
            sound: "default",
        });

        PushNotification.configure({
            onNotification: function (notification) {
                console.log("push notification");
                if (!notification.data) {
                    return;
                }
                notification.userInteraction = true;
                if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
                    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
                }
            },
            senderId: "1054317504462",
            permissions: {
                alert: true,
                badge: true,
                sound: true,
            },
            popInitialNotification: true,
            requestPermissions: true,
        });
    });
};

export const remoteMessage = () => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage1 => {
        console.log("A new FCM message arrived!", JSON.stringify(remoteMessage1));
    });
    return unsubscribe;
};
```

**screenshot of Signing and Certificates in XCODE**
[image]

**AppDelegate code**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "RNNotifications.h"

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 [FIRApp configure];
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"AirU_App"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```